# Django keep getting 104 connection reset by peer caused by adding simple video, can't forward video

Tags: django

I want to add video to my django template. When I add it, video is unforwardable (I can't skip this video to other point, I can just play it from start to the end). Excatly the same issue happens when I open link to video in new browser tab.

When I close/refresh this page console shows:

```
[19/Jun/2019 11:22:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9386
[19/Jun/2019 11:22:23] "GET /media/audio_and_video/videoplayback_lzlCjOR_Ftjx0GJ.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 9431145
[19/Jun/2019 11:22:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9386
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 44798)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/dolidod/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

Model:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    miniature = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/track', default="defaults/default.png", validators=[validate_miniature_file_extension])
    audio_or_video = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_and_video/', default="file_not_found", validators=[validate_track_file_extension])
    favourite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Template (".fields" because I use vuejs, but link to video works exactly as src='{{ track.audio_or_video.url }}', error was happening even when I wasn't using vue):

```
<video width='400' controls>
    <source :src="'/media/' + track.fields.audio_or_video" type='video/mp4'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

urls.py (main file from projectname/projectname):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Settings (I removed comments/database settings to short code):

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'rvl%g^%p$=vd1^_#j0yr2uy55*hr%)60wr&bk(#a&2qe==m54r'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'profiles',
    'app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MusicApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MusicApp.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'WebMediaFilesEditor',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'DemoPass#00',
  }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

SITE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for it ?

Comment: No, I abonaded this project for now. I may back to it in future. @ebeninki

Comment: @ebeninki check my answer if you are still interested

Answer (score 0):

I found that! I had to install another media player for my PC - I installed VLC and made it default software to openning .mp4s in my system, and then it worked in chrome as well.